# how to add command for carriage return ssrs to msword

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, carriage-return, mailmerge

Goal: To print a mailmerge report with one of the cell with 3 persons contact information ( with each person having name, cell, email)

Issue: All the data is junked up as we trying to display contact data in contact column and it is not persisting the carriage returns from procedure or ssrs.

In our application I am sending data from SSRS report and printing reports in MS Word (Mail Merge)

As I am sending data in one of the table a value which is brought from database is long and formatted. But the formatting is not persisting as the data is passed from ssrs to ms word(xml) via common reporting services.

I tried adding vbcrf / tried formatting data result from stored procedure/ tried adding /n/r as a string while sending the data from ssrs to services none of them are working.

The report looks odd because in one cell all the data is clumsy and has no carriage returns where necessary. I can't do this in separate cells since this is relevant to that column alone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what the report looks like in design, preview and as a word document?  If you have new lines in your report, they should be persisted in your word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line break in Microsoft Word is represented by a vertical tab - ASCII 11, Ctrl-K, or escape code `\v`.